# Why does 0x80000000 >> 1 in JavaScript produce a negative value?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

Doing some tests with bitwise operations / shifting with JavaScript

```
0x80000000 >> 1 // returns -1073741824 (-0x40000000)
```

I would expect that to return 0x40000000 since

```
0x40000000 >> 1 // returns 0x20000000
0x20000000 >> 1 // returns 0x10000000
```

Comment: That's because 0x800... is 0b10000..., and when you shift it right one place it becomes 0b1100..., a negative number. On the other hand, 0x400... is 0b0100... and 0x200... is 0b0010... and they don't have this problem.

Comment: @NullUserException sorry if this is very basic stuff, but why does it not become 0b0100... ? can 0x80.. be shifted so it produces a positive 0x40.. ?

Comment: @NullUserException: Should be an answer

Comment: @lostsource: Because there's nothing to "overwrite" the original value of that most-significant bit. Usually you'd apply a mask with `&` after performing a shift.

Comment: thank you everyone for the information, I now understand the difference between an `arithmetic` and a `logical` shift

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its an [arithmetic shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) that's why the sign is preserved, to do a [logical shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift) use [`>>>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#%3E%3E%3E_%28Zero-fill_right_shift%29)

```
0x80000000 >>> 1 // returns 1073741824 (0x40000000)
```

Answer (score 4):

In Javascript, `>>` is the *Signed Right Shift Operator*. In §11.7.2 of the [language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) it says:

> Performs a sign-filling bitwise right shift operation on the left operand by the amount specified by the right operand.

Before the shifting is done, the left operand is converted to a signed 32-bit integer (step 5 of the algorithm given in the specification). In your case this conversion turns the given positive number into a negative value. After that, the actual shifting is done, preserving the negative sign of the value.